# verification of<...>

Tags: sentence-construction

Is the use of "verification" in the following sentence correct grammatically and conceptually? If it is not, kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> The **verification** of the author’s responses by the reviewers shows
>   the paper quality.

Comment: Unless you explain what you're trying to say exactly, it's difficult for us to figure out whether your sentence is clear, or there is a better way to express it.

Comment: My technical paper is reviewed by two reviewers. the opinion of reviewers was good with respect to the responses. For this reason, I used verification.

Comment: Another nitpick is "paper quality" vs "paper's quality." "paper quality" may indicate if the physical paper the words are written on is sturdy. Paper's quality is more precise, with the contents of the paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence is correct grammatically but I suspect it might not carry your intended meaning. The construction "verification of A by B" can be reworded as:

> verification of A by B = B is asserting that A is correct.

So in your sentence, the **reviewers** are asserting that **the author's responses** are correct. If that is your intended meaning, then you are correct. However, I suspect you intended meaning is:

> The verification of the paper by the reviewers shows its quality.

It seems more reasonable to me that the reviewers would be verifying the entire paper (rather than just the author's responses).

Also, as a small note, I think it might be slightly incorrect to simply state **paper quality**. You are speaking specifically about the quality of a particular paper. So it would be better to use a possessive, **the paper's quality**. Further, **paper quality** is a common expression that refers to the physical makeup of the paper (as opposed to the contents of the essay).

Comment: Verification to me implies a test or check of the validity of something I wonder if there isn't a better word--corroboration? validation?--for reviewing something and finding it sound.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence

> The verification of the author’s responses by the reviewers shows the paper quality.

as it stands can be understood to mean "*reviewers*" are commenting on the "*author's responses*" (to the reviewers?) and somehow that is related to the "*quality of the paper*".  This would not be considered "*verification*" *of the paper*.

Usually it might be phrased as

> The verification *(of the paper)* by the reviewers shows the quality of the author's paper, since this *directly* addresses the "*paper*", whereas your original sentence is more *indirect*.

but this may have a different meaning than you originally intended.